# Not able to access samba shares but visible in network

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

In Windows it asks for username & password & in Ubuntu it asks for username, domain & password.

I entered root's and local user's password it says NOT ACCESSIBLE.

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
    workgroup = test
    netbios name = bishwa

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
   wins support = yes

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
    dns proxy = no

# What naming service and in what order should we use to resolve host names
# to IP addresses
   name resolve order = wins lmhosts host bcast

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
    max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
    syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# "security = user" is always a good idea. This will require a Unix account
# in this server for every user accessing the server. See
# /usr/share/doc/samba-doc/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/ServerType.html
# in the samba-doc package for details.
    security = user

# You may wish to use password encryption.  See the section on
# 'encrypt passwords' in the smb.conf(5) manpage before enabling.
    encrypt passwords = yes

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
    passdb backend = tdbsam

    obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
    unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
    pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
    map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

# Is this machine able to authenticate users. Both PDC and BDC
# must have this setting enabled. If you are the BDC you must
# change the 'domain master' setting to no
#
    domain logons = yes
    domain master = yes
;   local master = yes
    preferred master = yes
    os level = 64
#
# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of the user's profile directory
# from the client point of view)
# The following required a [profiles] share to be setup on the
# samba server (see below)
    logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
    logon drive = H:
;   logon home = \\%n\%u

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
    add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

########## Printing ##########

# If you want to automatically load your printer list rather
# than setting them up individually then you'll need this
#   load printers = yes

# lpr(ng) printing. You may wish to override the location of the
# printcap file
;   printing = bsd
;   printcap name = /etc/printcap

# CUPS printing.  See also the cupsaddsmb(8) manpage in the
# cupsys-client package.
;   printing = cups
;   printcap name = cups

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Most people will find that this option gives better performance.
# See smb.conf(5) and /usr/share/doc/samba-doc/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/speed.html
# for details
# You may want to add the following on a Linux system:
#         SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
#   socket options = TCP_NODELAY

# The following parameter is useful only if you have the linpopup package
# installed. The samba maintainer and the linpopup maintainer are
# working to ease installation and configuration of linpopup and samba.
;   message command = /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/linpopup "%f" "%m" %s; rm %s' &

# Domain Master specifies Samba to be the Domain Master Browser. If this
# machine will be configured as a BDC (a secondary logon server), you
# must set this to 'no'; otherwise, the default behavior is recommended.
#   domain master = auto

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# The following was the default behaviour in sarge,
# but samba upstream reverted the default because it might induce
# performance issues in large organizations.
# See Debian bug #368251 for some of the consequences of *not*
# having this setting and smb.conf(5) for details.
;   winbind enum groups = yes
;   winbind enum users = yes

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
    usershare allow guests = yes
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
;   guest ok = no
;   guest account = nobody

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each 
# user's home director as \\server\username
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = no
    writable = yes

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server. Un-comment the following parameter
# to make sure that only "username" can connect to \\server\username
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
#
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
[netlogon]
    comment = Network Logon Service
    path = /home/samba/netlogon
    guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
[profiles]
    comment = Users profiles
    path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
    browseable = no
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
;   guest ok = no
;   read only = yes
    create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
;   browseable = yes
;   read only = yes
;   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

# A sample share for sharing your CD-ROM with others.
;[cdrom]
;   comment = Samba server's CD-ROM
;   read only = yes
;   locking = no
;   path = /cdrom
;   guest ok = yes

# The next two parameters show how to auto-mount a CD-ROM when the
#   cdrom share is accesed. For this to work /etc/fstab must contain
#   an entry like this:
#
#       /dev/scd0   /cdrom  iso9660 defaults,noauto,ro,user   0 0
#
# The CD-ROM gets unmounted automatically after the connection to the
#
# If you don't want to use auto-mounting/unmounting make sure the CD
#   is mounted on /cdrom
#
;   preexec = /bin/mount /cdrom
;   postexec = /bin/umount /cdrom

[mail]
    path = /home/frigate/mail
    writable = yes
    browseable = yes


[thunderbird]
    path = /home/frigate/Desktop/thunderbird
    writable = yes
    browseable = yes
```

Comment: Accessing Samba shares requires that you authenticate to the machine hosting the share with credentials for the sharing host, not the client accessing it. Have you tried authenticating with the  username/password combo for the share host?

Comment: Cant understand "authenticating with the username/password combo for the share host?" please can you be more specific...

Comment: To access the Samba share, you have to use a username and password pair that exist on the machine that the share sits on (the host). It looks like you posted your Samba config file - are you trying to access a share on your Ubuntu machine, or a share on Windows machine?

Comment: i can access both windows and ubuntu shares but when i try to access my ubuntu pc from any other windows or ubuntu pc it asks for username and password.

Comment: That is how it should be. Now that we clearly understand what's going on, we can work towards a solution. I'll work on posting an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you are a root user so open up terminal and type. note this is for my server yours will use a different names but the actions will be the same.

```
geoff*testserver:-$ sudo passwd root
 [sudo] password for geoff:
 Enter new unix password:
 Retype new unix password:
 passwd: password updated successfully
 geoff*testserver:-$
```

ok you can now take control as a root user next.
now you need to give the server a static ip address so type in

```
geoff*testserver:-$ su
Password:

root*testserver:/home/geoff* ifconfig         (this will show all the nics)
```

so take note of the bcast number and the netmask number now we will setup the static ip address.

```
root*testserver:/home/geoff* vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

you will now look for the line `iface eth0 inet dchp`

press INSERT on your keyboard and change dchp to static then add the details so your script will look like this.

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
 gateway 192.168.1.1
```

when you have finished press escape the type `:wq` this will write and save the script. now you will restart the network type in

```
root*testserver: /home/geoff* /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

now see if all is well by doing an update so type

```
root*testserver: /home/geoff* apt-get update
```

you should see lots of lines of data scroll the screen this will confirm you configured the network and you can receive updates.
if you only get errors you need to go back and fix it try different gateway.    ok all good so far. next install

```
root*testserver: /home/geoff* apt-get install openssh-server samba smbclient cifs-utils ntp ntpdate
```

click `y` for the install now we will create the shared directories

```
root*testserver:/home/geoff* cd
 root*testserver:# mkdir /files
```

now we can make our folders i will make two

```
root*testserver:# mkdir /files/public
root=testserver:# mkdir /files/geoff
```

now we make them useable so type in

```
 root*testserver:# chmod 777 /files/public
 root=testserver:# chmod 777 /files/geoff
```

do this for every folder you make

so the next part we will edit samba this is important so take care

```
root*testserver:# vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

you will now be in the samba configuration file when we have done the edits your files will be on you network to everyone.

scroll down to workgroup setting and edit this to your network name this is important to windows machines , I have set mine to **BLACKBIRD**

dont forget to press INSERT on your keyboard so you can edit the files. ok scroll down and remove the hash tag from " wins support " and change the value from no to yes.

scroll down and remove the semi colon from "resolve name order"

scroll down and remove the hash tag from "security = user"

then scroll down again all the way to the bottom till you cant go any further
then type in the following so we can enable the share folders

```
[ Geoff's files]
 comment = Geoff's files
 path = /files/geoff
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
[ Public files]
 comment = Public files
 path = /files/public
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
```

now hit the escape key on your keyboard the type `:wq` this will write and save your edit.

now we will add a samba password some computers will ask for this so,,

```
root*testserver:# smbpasswd -a geoff
 New SMB password
 Retype new SMB password:
```

Ok all is now complete restart your server your folder will be visible to all on your network , please note this is LINUX where spaces and uppercase and lowercase matters good luck..

Comment: OKzz i can access those folders from ubuntu machine but i can't access them from windows pc

Comment: I realise it's an old thread I'm commenting on here but Ubuntu comes without a root password set to increase security and by setting one, especially as part of an answer for something totally different, you're decreasing security. A better way to switch to a root shell is to run `sudo su`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a Samba password for my user before I could enter and access any shares the PC advertised:

```
smbpasswd -a [username]
```

Even though you've set `security = user`, by default Samba doesn't check against your system password file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `smb.conf`entry, the first thing that jumps out at me is in the **Domains** section where you have:

```
    domain logons = yes
    domain master = yes
;   local master = yes
    preferred master = yes
    os level = 64
```

which indicates that you have configured Samba to act as a Primary Domain Controller (PDC). Unless you are running a group of Windows computers which need resource controls (very unlikely), this is not needed. You can disable that function by inserting a semi-colon `;` at the start of each line I listed, just like one is already there for `; local master = yes`. You will need to edit the file with `sudo` privileges by opening a Terminal session and using `sudo pico /etc/samba/smb.conf`. (I prefer `pico` for most of my command line text editing, but you can use the editor of your liking.) Once you make and save the changes, issue `sudo service samba restart` to have Samba restart and load the changed configuration.

Comment: ok now i am accessing shared folder from windows and it ask for username and password then i have to create users in ubuntu and give him smbpassword??

Comment: @BishwanathDas If you have a user account on the Ubuntu machine besides `root` enter that username and password pair to access the share.

Comment: OKzz i can access those folders from ubuntu machine but i can't access them from windows pc

Comment: @BishwanathDas Use the same username and password pair.

Comment: Using the same not working... it says \\share1 is not accessible contact system administrator (in windows)

Comment: @BishwanathDas  Linux can be picky about how you format the username, particularly preferring the shortname. So if your user account was `Bishwanath Das` the short name would be `bishwanathdas`  Try that and see what happens.

Comment: i had created a user test and set smbpasswd for test, so while i use user test with smbpasswd from ubuntu machine it gives me access, but when i do the same from windows machine it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

If your SMB server is old (e.g. case Win Server 2003) and your Ubuntu is new enough (18), you might have to add `vers=1.0` to the mount option. I upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 18 and found my old SMB shares wouldn't mount without explicitly adding that mount option.